# request for a small help with javascript

Tags: javascript

The following code validates the number of days of month depending on the month selected in the form. The month values start from Jan to Dec, days from 1 to 31 and year from 1900 to 2010. I am trying to make a very small change, I want to add the very first option in each of the three drop down boxes, a blank select option or for example a dash. so that the month drop down's first option is - instead of Jan. For this purpose, I'm adding following line in each drop down.

```
<option value=""> - </option>
```

But by adding this, it does not show the number of days of January and February correctly (it shows 1 day less than it should). This is some javascript problem, but I don't understand what is wrong. I shall be so thankful if you can help me with it.
Here's complete code for HTML, Javascript and php to populate the form.

```
<?php
$monthOptions = '';
$dayOptions = '';
$yearOptions = '';
 for($month=1; $month<=12; $month++){
    $monthName = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));
    $monthOptions .= "<option value=\"{$month}\">{$monthName}</option>\n";
} for($day=1; $day<=31; $day++){
    $dayOptions .= "<option value=\"{$day}\">{$day}</option>\n";
} for($year=1900; $year<=2010; $year++){
    $yearOptions .= "<option value=\"{$year}\">{$year}</option>\n";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateDays()
{
    //Create variables needed
    var monthSel = document.getElementById('month');
    var daySel   = document.getElementById('day');
    var yearSel  = document.getElementById('year');
    var monthVal = monthSel.value;
    var yearVal  = yearSel.value;

    //Determine the number of days in the month/year
    var daysInMonth = 31;
    if (monthVal==2){
        daysInMonth = (yearVal%4==0 && (yearVal%100!=0 || yearVal%400==0)) ? 29 : 28;
    } else if (monthVal==4 || monthVal==6 || monthVal==9 || monthVal==11) {
        daysInMonth = 30;
    }   
    //Add/remove options from days select list as needed
    if(daySel.options.length > daysInMonth){   //Remove excess days, if needed
        daySel.options.length = daysInMonth;
    } while (daySel.options.length != daysInMonth){   //Add additional days, if needed
        daySel.options[daySel.length] = new Option(daySel.length+1, daySel.length+1, false);
    }   
    return;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
Birthdate:<br />
<select name="month" id="month" onchange="updateDays();">
<?php echo $monthOptions; ?>
</select>

<select name="day" id="day">
<?php echo $dayOptions; ?>
</select>

<select name="year" id="year" onchange="updateDays();">
<?php echo $yearOptions; ?>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an optgroup instead:

`<optgroup label="-">
...
</optgroup>`

btw, nice name!

Answer (score 0):

Do not re-invent the wheel, use built-in Date object for checking dates.

```
function daysInMonth(year, month) {
  return (new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate();
}
```

Also there's an error in your code: "{" just before the comment "Remove excess days, if needed" isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want?

http://plungjan.name/scripts/date/calendars/datepickers/seldate.html

Let me know if you have questions or need a modification